# Display single image in a popover

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode5, uipopovercontroller

Can someone please write me a chunk of code that takes a UIImage and displays it in an UIPopoverController. Also so that the UIImage resizes based on the size of the popover window. I've been trying to do this for over 2 hours now and nothing seems to work.

I created an UImageView

```
UIImageView *photoToShowInPopover = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Then put it into a UIViewController

```
UIViewController *popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[popoverContent.view addSubview:photoToShowInPopover];
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 350);
```

Then put that into a UIPopoverController and displayed it

```
self.photoPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    self.photoPopover.delegate = self;
    [self.photoPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 350)];
    [self.photoPopover presentPopoverFromRect:icon.frame inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

This creates a popover, but the image is way smaller than the actual popover (it is in original size). How to I make it to scale to fit the popover window? The final functionality i want it to have is that, there is an image, which if i click, will display the same image, but larger in a popover.

Comment: What is the frame of photoToShowInPopover?

Comment: Im not sure, i didn't set it, because I initialized it with an UIImage

Comment: Size of any view depend on its frame and bounds. set it and all is well.

Comment: i tried, and it for some reason becomes larger than the popover. it there any way to regulate the size of the subview of a popover?

Comment: Post code of what u tried.